# Ipad play incomplete video file

Tags: ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to get the MPMovieplayerController to play incomplete video files. I want to use this so a user can download a part of a movie and play it offline. I am using ASIHTTP so i can resume downloads, if i try to play the temporary the player does nothing and and i get no errors. Also i registered for the MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification notification but it does not get dispatched. When the file is done downloading i can play it correctly.

Is it possible to somehow play incomplete video files? Alternatives to MPMovieplayerController are also welcome if that offers a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to download the first part op the mp4 file and the last part before i was able to play the video. So i am now downloading the first mb of the file then the last mb then the middle part and now i can play the file while it is not complete.

Comment: How were you able to download the last mb? Do share.

Comment: Would also like to know this or did you work out the bytes to put on the end?

Comment: I did a request to get the file size first, then using the byte-range header i did a request to download the last 2MB of the file. I used http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/.